# Angular.js - Identify controller called via route or ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller called 'signin'

```
    app.controller('signin', function() {
      setPageTitle('Sign In');
    });
```

In routes, i routed this controller to '/signin'

Also, i used this same controller for my sign in popup via directive

```
<div class="popup" ng-controller="signin"></div>
```

when this controller is called, the page title will set as 'Sign In',

All works fine, But issue is,

I don't want to set the pageTitle while calling via the directive (ng-controller)

How can i do this ? something like

```
    app.controller('signin', function() {
      if(viaRoute) {
         setPageTitle('Sign In');
      }
    });
```

Comment: you can use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) and set the `$scope` variable `viaRoute` there.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, you can pass a parameter to the controller via resolve:

```
templateUrl: 'template.html',
controller: 'signin',
resolve: {
     viaRoute: function(){
        return true;
     }
},
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('signin', function(viaRoute) {
    if (viaRoute) {
        setPageTitle('Sign In');
    }
});
```